# How to setup a remote SMTP connection to Exchange Online Protection / Exchange?

Tags: exchange-2010

My remote webserver can't connect to my exchange server, below is what I've tried so far:

**From my remote webserver:**

`telnet example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com 25` or 587 results in a "Trying x.x.x.x..."

`ping example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com` is successful

```
traceroute example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com 25 reaches inbound.protection.outlook.com with no errors
```

**From my local network where exchange server is located:**

`telnet example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com 25` results in a successful connection to the exchange server

`ping` works fine too...

Note. Our exchange server can send and receives emails for all local users.

My best guess is an inbound connector is not setup properly and or a firewall is blocking the connection to port 25.

I've tried opening port 25 on our Sonicwall for only our webserver's ip, telneting resulted in same "Trying x.x.x.x"...

I've also tried setting up a inbound "partner" connector in EOP specifying just the webservers ip and that actually broke the relay for all emails and also didn't work...

I'm not sure if I'm on the right track here and could use some guidance.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you've got the right FQDN, and Exchange Online won't block inbound access to that FQDN on port 25 by default so that it can accept inbound email from any sender domain (normal email).

The fact that you can ping it, and that you can get there from your local network means it is most likely on the webserver's side where the problem lies.

So if that's the case, then you are down to a few possibilities, some of which are:

1. Possible outbound firewall on your webserver's LAN/WAN side.  Can it send and connect to other mail servers on port 25 fine?
2. The webserver's ISP/connection doesn't allow outbound port 25 unless you go through their mail servers.  This is typically done for home ISPs but some business ISPs can prevent this as well.  You'd have to check with them to find out if this is the case or try to telnet from your network to port 25 on the O365 submission server FQDN.

So from what you've described it shouldn't have anything to do with your Exchange Online account itself, but everything to do with your webserver's side of things.

As discussed in comments below if your VPS at Godaddy blocks outbound port 25 either relay through them (which is easy enough...) or use port 587 and submit through authentication with O365 (see below link for details).

For better reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365

Comment: My web server (VPS) is hosted on GoDaddy, I can confirm outbound port 25 is blocked. I have tested port 587 and that port is NOT blocked, however example-com.mail.protection.outlook.com doesn't accept 587...

Comment: @TheCleaner It's the other way around. Port 25 is for SMTP relay and only works through the [tenant].mail.protection.outlook.com subdomain. Port 587 is for mail user agents to connect.

Comment: @AaronQueenan - correct!  Sorry.  I'll delete my erroneous comment.  For future reference for others, please use the MS link for further understanding of SMTP submissions and relays: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365